# Momentum which is transfered to the wall of container by a molecule

Tags: thermodynamics, momentum

now I study thremodynamics course, and I cant understand why for ideal gas in equilibrium state when a molecule collides with the wall of container it transfers to it the momentum which is equals to $2mv$, where $m$ is the mass of the molecule and $v$ - is it's speed. Why it is not just $mv$, but double of that?

I suspect that the answer is connected with the conservation of momentum principle, but it is not obvious for me. Please help me understand.

Comment: The wall is at rest, the total momentum is mv. in order to have momentum conservation mv=-mv+2mv.  - because direction was reversed, and then the 2 so that the equation ( momentum conservation ) holds

Comment: ok so we add to the equation the initial momentum of the wall? I supposed that it was $0$. So we have $mv=-mv$, but it is not true, and for the equation to hold it needs the momentum of the wall to be equal $2mv$. Is it correct understanding?

Comment: Before hit, the momentum of the wall is zero so the total momentum wall+molecule is the mv of the molecule, and this is what has to be conserved after the hit.

Comment: @annav your comments should be an answer

Comment: @annav I got it, thnx for the explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the initial momentum is $mv$, then when the particle bounces off the wall, it is going in the opposite direction, so its new momentum is $-mv$. The difference is $2mv$ because $mv - (-mv) = 2mv$.

By the way, this is not really how it works; molecules will speed up or slow down when they hit the wall. If the molecule is moving slowly, it's likely to speed up, and if it's going fast, it's likely to slow down. The calculation is just for what happens on average.